# EF Core introducing foreign key constraint on table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a User entity:

```cs
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

and a Message entity:

```cs
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    
    public User Sender { get; set; }
    
    public User? Recipient { get; set; }

}
```

and my context is configured like this:

```cs
public class DummyContext: DbContext
{
    public DummyContext(DbContextOptions<DummyContext> options)
        : base(options){ }

    public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; } = null!;

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Everything works fine and i can add-migration and update-database

Then i try to add another Invoice entity:

```cs
public class Invoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public User Sender { get; set; }

    public User Recipient { get; set; }

    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }

    public float Amount { get; set; }
}
```

and add the DbSet to the context

```cs
...
public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices{ get; set; } = null!;
...
```

This time i add-migration and update-database but it gives me an error:

> The introduction of the FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Invoices_Users_SenderUsername' in the 'Invoices' table can result in the creation of loops or more propagation paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION or change the other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

And i cant quite figure out why it wasnt giving me the same error for the messages,
I want the message to delete on cascade if the user is deleted and that works fine but as soon as i try to do the same thing with the invoices it gives me this error.
I dont want to add OnDelete No action since i want the invoices to get deleted on user deletion too.

Comment: It just means that you cannot cascade multiple deletions automatically. You are required to set it to no action and then delete the children yourself first. It can still appear automatic to the user but you'll have to write code to delete the children.

Comment: It's because `Invoice.Recipient` isn't nullable. That makes EF generate two FKs with cascaded delete. But IMO you shouldn't want any cascaded delete from User to Invoice. Suppose by some bug a user gets deleted inadvertently. Then you really don't want Invoices to disappear.

Comment: Ty, @GertArnold this solved my issue but what if i want 2 fks with on delete cascade? in this example i want a class to be deleted if both the sender or the recipient is deleted, (the invoice class was an example)

Comment: Can't be done. SQL Server doesn't allow it.

Comment: @DavideCavazzuti *"but what if i want 2 fks with on delete cascade?"* You can't. This is a famous long time SqlServer specific limitation with no other solution then turning off the cascade delete for one or more of the relationships forming the potential multiple cascade paths and handle the deletion manually or via db triggers.

Comment: @Gert Something interesting I'm noticing for the first time. They changed the error message to "can result in the creation of loops or more propagation paths", so now one can't simply search for "cycles or multiple cascade paths" and find a tons of duplicates :( And in general, I'm not a native English speaker, but I find it much easier to explain "multiple cascade paths" then "more propagation paths".

Comment: @Ivan Yeah, I also noticed the uncommon exception message. The funny thing is, it doesn't get any hits in Google when looking for the exact phrase. I think it's a translation artifact.